# How can i make this batch program more efficient

Tags: batch-file

A friend of mine asked me to make a program that would print a string of random 1's and 0's in a matrix like fashion.  I agreed and succeeded in writing a program in batch that has the desired output but it runs kind of slow and i was wondering if there was a way i could make it more efficient

```
set count=0

:loopassign
if %count%==80 goto show
set/a count=%count%+1
set/a value=%random% %% 2
set number%count%=%value%
goto loopassign

:show
echo {             %number1%%number2%%number3%%number4%%number5%%number6%%number7%%number8%%number9%%number10%%number11%%number12%%number13%%number14%%number15%%number16%%number17%%number18%%number19%%number20%%number21%%number23%%number24%%number25%%number26%%number27%%number28%%number29%%number30%%number31%%number32%%number33%%number43%%number44%%number45%%number46%%number47%%number48%%number49%%number50%%number51%%number52%%number53%%number54%%number55%%number56%%number57%%number58%%number59%%number60%%number61%%number62%%number63%%number64%%number65%%number66%%number67%%number68%%number69%%number70%%number71%%number72%%number73%%number74%%number75%%number76%%number77%%number78%%number79%%number80% }
set count=0
goto loopassign
```

Answer (score 1):

The main time consuming part is the `goto loopassign`.
This can be replaced by a FOR /L loop.

The loop is better than the goto, as it's no longer necessary to scan the complete file while searching the label.
And the code inside the for-block is cached and just once parsed, therefore the execution is much faster.

That I use a single line variable instead of 80 variables for a single character is only for maintainability.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set count=0

:loopassign
set "line="
for /L %%n in (1,1,80) do (
    set /a "value=!random! & 1"
    set "line=!line!!value!"
)

:show
echo {             !line! }
goto loopassign
```

**More improved speed variant**

You can easily speed up it more with a simple trick to generate in each loop four instead of one characters, so you need only 20 loops for a single line.

```
for /L %%n in (1,1,20) do (
    set /a "n=!random! & 15,m=10000+(n&8)*125+(n&4)*25+(n&2)*5+(n & 1)"
    set "ln=!ln!!m:~-4!"
)
```

This seems to be three times faster

Comment: +1, You beat me to it, but I posted virtually the same thing anyway, with an outer infinite FOR loop.

Comment: +1 To you too, the outer loop doesn't noticeable improve the speed, but the nibble technic is three times faster :-)

Comment: ooh - that is nasty. I like it :) For a while I thought you could do up to 9 digits per loop, but then I remembered `%random%` maxes out at 32767. Why the `& 15`? That seems unneccessary.

Comment: The '&15' isn't necessary, first I wanted to implement a mapping solution, like the one of Aacini.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about

- **FOR loops:** Type `HELP FOR` from the command prompt. In particular, you want the FOR /L option
- **Delayed Expansion:** type `HELP SET` from the command prompt. The section about delayed expansion is about halfway through the help.

Here is a solution that uses 2 FOR /L loops. The outer loop is infinite because it never increments the counter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%Z in (0 0 1) do (
  set "ln="
  for /l %%N in (1 1 80) do (
    set /a "n=!random! %% 2"
    set "ln=!ln!!n!"
  )
  echo {             !ln! }
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

I love the speed test programs! I think the mine below would be faster...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a Decimal-to-Binary conversion table for values from 0 to 15
set dec=0
for %%n in (0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111
            1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111 ) do (
   set bin[!dec!]=%%n
   set /A dec+=1
)

rem Repeat the loop 5 times per line
set line=
for /L %%n in (1,1,5) do (
   rem Generate 4 groups of 4 bits per cycle
   set /A "G1=(n=!random!)&15, G2=(n>>=(G1&3)+1)&15, G3=(n>>=4)&15, G4=(n>>4)&15"
   for /F "tokens=1-4" %%a in ("!G1! !G2! !G3! !G4!") do (
      set line=!line!!bin[%%a]!!bin[%%b]!!bin[%%c]!!bin[%%d]!
   )
)
echo {             %line%}
```

Antonio

**EDIT:** I slightly modified the expression to avoid zeros at 5 fixed positions in the line of 80 binary digits.

Comment: Nice, but I suppose the highest bit is always 0, as %random% uses only 15 bit

Comment: @jeb: Oops, you are right, jeb! This produce zeros at 5 fixed positions in the 80 binary digits. I fixed this problem with a little trick ;-)